# Aar file classes not accessible to other module android?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

My project is in multi module setup

Modules - `app, m1, m2`

`m1` module has an aar library`(lib1)` which resides in `libs folder`.

`m2` module has dependency of m1 module.

I am not able to access `lib1` files in `m2` module.

`m1` level gradle has

```
implementation (files("libs/lib1.aar"))
```

`m2` level gradle has

```
api(project(":m1"))
```

Comment: Either add lib1.aar in both module or create a wrapper class (arround  lib1 functionality)inside m1 which is accessible to m2

Answer (score 0):

`api(project(":m1"))` inside **m2**'s `build.gradle` means that **m1** dependency will be accessible in the modules that have **m2** as a dependency.

i.e. if your **app**'s `build.gradle` has **m2**, then it has access to entities from **m1**, in case **m1** is added to **m2** via `api`.

Thus, please try `api (files("libs/lib1.aar"))`